# how to fix error of insufficient space

Tags: google-play-store

Even though I have tons of memory I can't install apps because it shows insufficient memory in Google play..I tried all things such as uninstalling Google play store and typing *#9900# and clearing the data still it's not helping me...Please do something

Comment: Take a look at similar questions tagged under [tag:insufficient-memory]. Also, could you post a screenshot of the Play Store error, and the status of Storage available.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem a few days ago. All I did was clearing all the data and cache of all Google related apps especially Play Store, Google Play Services, Google Play Framework, and Download manager. Next removing the Google account itself from the phone. Reboot the device and start fresh everything.